# cron is truncating environment variables containing a hash

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I export my environment variables with `env >> /etc/environment` to expose them to my cron jobs.

However one of my environment variables, a password, contains a hash sign `#`...

Sure enough, when the cron job executes, everything after `#` has disappeared!

How do I avoid that?

#### To reproduce

Be aware that `env >> /etc/environment` writes the environment in this globally accessible file - I don't care since I run in a docker container but you might.

```bsh
export cron_test=123#456
# This will show 123#456
echo $cron_test 
# Take care with the line below
env >> /etc/environment
crontab -e

# and start cron if it is not running
```

When prompted by crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * echo $cron_test > /tmp/cron.env
```

After a minute `cat /tmp/cron.env` will only show `123` instead of `123#456`.

Any workaround much appreciated.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/539730/environment-variable-in-etc-environment-with-pound-hash-sign-in-the-value

Comment: Thanks. So since this is a known bug/feature of `/etc/environment`... The question remains: how can I pass an environment variable (containing a hash sign) to a cron job? I don't have to use `/etc/environment`, any workaround will do!

Comment: Tried adding `cron_test=123#456` to crontab directly?